# How to capture application crash stack?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Generally, crash can be catch by Application.UnhandledException, but sometimes, crash can't get there, I don't know why, how can I get this kinds of crash stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using free version of https://www.bugsense.com/, really useful to get all the information from a crash.

Documentation for Windows Phone 8 [installation](https://www.bugsense.com/docs/windowsphone8) (3 simple steps).